# Object literal function creation

Tags: javascript

Can't find this info anywhere on the web. Is there **any** difference (e.g. in performance) between these two methods created with object literal syntax? Or is the mechanism under the hood exactly the same?

```
let test = {

  foo(){
    console.log("foo");
    return 1;
  },
  bar: () => {
    console.log("bar");
    }
}


console.log(test.foo());
console.log(test.bar());
```

Comment: Yes; `this` will be different.

Comment: `foo` returns a value of `1`, `bar` returns `undefined`

Comment: To elaborate on Slaks comment above... `this` will be bound to the lexical scope of `test` with an arrow function, whereas `this` will be `undefined` in `foo`. Take a look at [the MDN docs on arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any performance difference -- the shorthand function property is just syntactic sugar.

However, there's an operational difference. The shorthand notation is short for the traditional function syntax, not an arrow function. So it's equivalent to:

```
foo: function() {
    console.log("foo");
}
```

Arrow functions have a number of different behaviors from traditional function expressions. See [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Your example functions don't do anything that depends on the differences, but in a real application they might.

Comment: I would've thought `bar:() => { console.log("bar"); }` was equivalent to `bar: function() {
    console.log("bar");
    }.bind(this)` (where `this` would NOT be `test` as it is in `foo`)

Comment: @JaromandaX That's the main difference, but there are others.